# Error in android set focus

Tags: android, focus

I created an activity containing three *EditText*

When i press "enter key" in *edittext1* the focus must change to *edittext2.*

This is my code

```
 final EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
 final EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        e1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    e2.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

but, the focus is changing to *edittext3*

What i can do?

---

i try one solution but not work
my code xml is

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
     >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:text="@string/location_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="@string/barcode_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minLines="1" />
```

when i type "enter" in edit1 the focus change to editText3 not to editText2

Comment: request fouse in xml

Answer (score 2):

Define the below in the XML under the `first_edit_text` attribute

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/second_edit_text"
```

Example,

```
<EditText
    android:id="first_edit_text"
    .
    .
    .
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/second_edit_text"
   />

<EditText
    android:id="second_edit_text"
    .
    .
    .
    />
```

This will set the next focus view for your edit text using XML. I hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

For your specific case add the attributes to the `EditText1` like below,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText2"
     >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

In xml do like this.its work fine.noo nedd to put any extra code.

in activity use your code.it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
edtName.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.edtAddress);

        edtName.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                edtName.clearFocus();
                edtAddress.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```